# Is it possible to have a data type that has just one constructor of another data type?

Tags: haskell, types, constructor

I have a (quite complex) data type:

```
data SomeDataType = Constructor Blah Blah Blah | OtherConstructor Blah Yadda | YetAnotherConstructor Yadda Yadda Tittle | StillOneMoreConstructor Tittle Tattle Wish Wash
```

Now I find myself wanting another data type… With two constructors. One would be identical to `YetAnotherConstructor` of `SomeDataType`; the other one would just store a `Double`. What are my options?

```
data WantedDataType = ConstructorName1 Double | ConstructorName2 SomeDataType
```

While this would work this would also allow stuff like `ConstructorName2 $ StillOneMoreConstructor tittle tattle wish wash` which makes no sense.

```
data WantedDataType = ConstructorName1 Double | ConstructorName2 Yadda Yadda Tittle
```

Again, this would work but it seems to me to be a violation of DRY and it might be tedious to convert stuff to and from `WantedDataType` and `SomeDataType`.

```
data WantedDataType = ConstructorName1 Double | YetAnotherConstructor Yadda Yadda Tittle
```

This is what I'd like most but unfortunately, Haskell doesn't seem to support this sort of polymorphism (a constructor can't belong simultaneously to two data types).

What are my options? How should I tackle this?

Comment: One way out would be spinning off `YetAnotherConstructor` into a different type, which you would then use in both `SomeDataType` and `WantedDataType`.

Answer (score 8):

This makes me think `YetAnotherConstructor` is actually "supposed" to be its own data type:

```
data YetAnotherData = YetAnotherConstructor Yadda Yadda Tittle
data SomeDataType   = Constructor Blah Blah Blah
                    | OtherConstructor Blah Yadda
                    | SomeYetAnotherConstructor {-!-}YetAnotherData
                    -- ! will make this EXACTLY isomorphic to the original 
                    -- but is likely unnecessary 
                    | StillOneMoreConstructor Tittle Tattle Wish Wash
data WantedDataType = ConstructorName1 Double
                    | ConstructorName2 {-!-}YetAnotherData
```

If it annoys you to say `SomeYetAnotherConstructor (YetAnotherConstructor _ _ _)` and `ConstructorName2 (YetAnotherData _ _ _)`, there's an extension for that (though I think you'll think it leads you back to square one):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern SomeYetAnother :: Yadda -> Yadda -> Tittle -> SomeDataType
pattern SomeYetAnother x y z = SomeYetAnotherConstructor (YetAnotherConstructor x y z)
{-# COMPLETE Constructor, OtherConstructor, SomeYetAnother, StillOneMoreConstructor #-}

pattern WantedYetAnother :: Yadda -> Yadda -> Tittle -> WantedDataType
pattern WantedYetAnother x y z = ConstructorName2 (YetAnotherConstructor x y z)
{-# COMPLETE ConstructorName1, WantedYetAnother #-}
```

This will make `SomeYetAnother` and `WantedYetAnother` act like data constructors (complete with coverage checking (`COMPLETE` pragmas), pattern matching, and construction). You can use them for constructing/matching on each type when you don't care about the fact that `YetAnotherData` is its own unit, and you can use the underlying `SomeYetAnotherConstructor` and `ConstructorName2` constructors if you want to treat the `YetAnotherData` as one unit. The latter may be useful for e.g.

```
someToWantedByYet :: SomeDataType -> Maybe WantedDataType
someToWantedByYet (SomeYetAnotherConstructor y) = Just $ ConstructorName2 y
someToWantedByYet _ = Nothing
wantedToSomeByYet :: WantedDataType -> Maybe SomeDataType
wantedToSomeByYet (ConstructorName2 y) = Just $ SomeYetAnotherConstructor y
wantedToSomeByYet _ = Nothing
```